# Jquery wrap element dynamically loaded after Dom

Tags: jquery

Situation: There is a video iframe inside a post that is loaded dynamically (ajax).

I need to wrap this iframe in a div "videoWrapper".

When I paste this code in the console (chrome) it does the job, the iframe is correctly wrapped by the div.

When I put his code in the live site, does not add the div to the html. 
It is not working in the live version.

How can I trigger the function on the last moment?

This is my current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
   jQuery('iframe[src*="youtube.com"], iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]').wrap('<div class="videoWrapper" />');
});
```

I have also tried

```
jQuery(document).on(function() { 
    jQuery('iframe[src*="youtube.com"], iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]')
       .wrap('<div class="videoWrapper" />'); }); 
});
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm really new in JS/jQuery.

I leave a copy of the HTML that is around the iframe:

```
<div class="eg-ajax-target-container-wrapper " id="sp-content-ajax">
    <!-- CONTAINER FOR PREFIX -->
    <div class="eg-ajax-target-prefix-wrapper">
    </div>
    <!-- CONTAINER FOR CONTENT TO LOAD -->
    <div class="eg-ajaxanimwrapper" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: auto; z-index: 0; min-height: 0px; max-height: none;"><div class="eg-ajax-target" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; height: auto;"><div class="eg-ajax-closer-wrapper eg-acp-tr eg-acp-light eg-acp-type1"><div class="eg-ajax-closer eg-ajax-navbt">X</div></div><h2>Motu Buu Acoustic Track 3</h2>
<p><iframe></iframe></p>
<h3>Sample</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div></div>
    <!-- CONTAINER FOR SUFFIX -->
    <div class="eg-ajax-target-suffix-wrapper">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/98e4w330/

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint? If I had to guess I would say that `ready` event isn't firing since the DOM is already ready.

Comment: Dear AtheistP3ace , yes,  you are right. How should I write the code to target a already loaded DOM? as I mentioned, the content is injected after the DOM is loaded via ajax. thank you for your feedback. peace.